# Mercedes-Benz W203 C220 CDI doesn't accelerates as it should

Tags: mercedes-benz, acceleration, egr, cdi, c220

First of all, sorry for my English.

I have a Mercedes W203 C220 CDI (first model 2001) and when I run the car in the morning or when I get back from work in the afternoon (after a few hours without using it), the car does not accelerates as it should and if I'm driving uphill it slow down even if I push the acceleration pedal completely.

If I run the car for 15 minutes or more, I turn it off and after a few seconds I turn it on again in the 90% of cases it works good and have a good acceleration.

In some cases it may get the full power itself without turning the car off when I'm using the A/C and the car is not moving (it makes a little vibration once with a small movement of engine revs) and that's the signal that the full power is restored.

A friend of mine is suggesting me to clean the EGR and that will be my next step, but first I wanted to know if someone here know something more about this issue.

Reading the codes was shown something about the Turbo solenoid pressure valve. I replaced it but nothing changed.

Comment: Have you read the codes? If not, then do so as this may help narrow down the problem.

Comment: The code shown was something about the turbo pressure solenoid on the passenger side. I changed it and nothing changed.

Comment: Edit you question with the information - people don't want to trawl through comments trying to piece together the full story.

Answer (score 0):

Some time after posting this question, the problem became permanent.
So after more than a year (without fault codes for this and a very lazy car), the problem was really a joke.

There were these two hoses coming out from the turbo vacuum boost behind the right headlight, [picture here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51NY%2BvSECYL._SX466_.jpg)).
One of these hoses was connected to the Turbo and the other was for the headlights to go up/down (as described by the service guy).

The hose that was meant for the headlights was removed so when the vacuum meant for the turbo came off from this hose. after connecting the hose back again to the headlights or just clamp it somehow to prevent the air to come off, finally the car was back to normal.

Note: there are two of these vacuum pumps (both sides), for me the problem was with the right one.

All the dirt accumulated in the turbo for a year started to come off as a black smoke (most on the first accelerations).

I hope with this answer to be helpful for someone that might have the same problem.